# Sql to select and extract 10 characters before and 10 characters after a substring in Oracle Clob

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

Let's consider the text example below:

> *Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
>   including versions of Lorem Ipsum.*

How do I extract 10 characters before and 10 characters after the substring, let's say 'Lorem Ipsum' from the above paragraph in Oracle? The datatype is clob. I have been trying with Oracle functions such as SUBSTR, but no luck so far. Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: So you want `industry. Lorem Ipsum has been ` in your output?

Comment: Do you need it to work on every occurrence of your given string or just the firsts or nth occurrence? what happens if an occurrence of your given string does not have previous/trailing characters?

Comment: What is the desired output - two new columns (in the output), one showing the ten characters before and the other the ten characters after? Then: Show NULL for the "ten characters before" if Lorem Ipsum is right at the beginning of the string? What if there are exactly six characters from the beginning of the string to Lorem Ipsum? Then: What if Lorem Ipsum appears more than once in the text? For example: what is the desired output from the string `'Lorem Ipsum wins. Lorem Ipsum.'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace` with back references:

```
select 
    regexp_replace(col, '.*?(.{0,10}Lorem Ipsum.{0,10}).*?','\1')
from t;
```

Here `.` matches any character and `?` is for lazy matching. For the given input, it produces:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simplyindustry. Lorem Ipsum has been ontaining Lorem Ipsum passages,rsions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried this. But I would like the output to be the following:
*Lorem Ipsum is simply, industry. Lorem Ipsum has been,  ontaining Lorem Ipsum passages, rsions of Lorem Ipsum.*

Comment: @user3376592 - Updated the answer. please try now.

Comment: @ Gurwinder Singh Thanks again for your help. The query appears to be right, but it is very slow and it returns the whole clob data as output instead of the string. The column datatype is clob. Do we need to do anything special to output as a string from the clob?

Comment: @user3376592 - If it's in a CLOB and the query is too slow for your needs, it should be re-written with standard string functions, not with regular expressions. It will still be slow, but not quite as slow. But first please see the questions I asked in a Comment under your original post - you need to give more details about the requirement itself.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for the clarification. The output should be this
**Lorem Ipsum is simply, industry. Lorem Ipsum has been, ontaining Lorem Ipsum passages, rsions of Lorem Ipsum.**
I hope the output makes sense. I need to match the 10 characters before and after 'Lorem Ipsum'. If there are no 10 characters before but 10 characters after, then show the 10 characters after along with the search text  'Lorem Ipsum'. For eg: 
**'Lorem Ipsum is simply' is a match
' industry. Lorem Ipsum has been' is a match
' ontaining Lorem Ipsum passages' is a match
'rsions of Lorem Ipsum.' is a match**